# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in Clion Mac ARM64

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clion

Im new to c++ and need help.

I generated an Clion c++11 project and got this example code: (project name is untitled, compiler for c++ = clang)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

I cant run my code in Clion. i get this error:
https://pastebin.com/jVka8dgs

Whats wrong?

Comment: My guess is its some type of compiler installation problem on macos.

Comment: If im doing this: ```int main() {
    printf("Hello, World");
    return 0;
}```
it compiles

Comment: I don't think your code or your CMakeLists.txt is the problem. I think the problem is the installation of your compiler. However I am not a macOS developer. You will probably have to get some confirmation from someone who is.

Comment: Please post the linker invocation, that should be shown right before. `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`.

Comment: ```====================[ Build | untitled | Debug ]================================
"/Users/flo/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/221.5591.52/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" --build /Users/flo/Workspace/Hochschule/Softwareproject/CPP/untitled/cmake-build-debug --target untitled -- -j 6
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my m1max mac.  You need to debug this with verbose cmake/ninja/make output to show the actual compiler and linker command.